# Writing CSS that works with CushyCMS?

Tags: css

Do anyone have experience in crafting CSS stylesheets for websites that will implement CushyCMS? My attempts haven't been working that well. I've had problems with the WYSIWYG interface, where clients email me a week or two after I considered the project a done deal and complain because when they updated the website using the WYSIWYG interface it didn't style things as they wanted or, in some cases, CushyCMS didn't input valid HTML so everything got screwed up (e.g. all text became bold because a tag was closed properly).

Got any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I've used CushyCMS for clients to update their sites and i suppose you just have to be careful which elements you put the class cmseditable on. I suppose at the end of the day if they wanted to change that much, then its a "site re-design" not a "client updating a few bits of text". Just dont apply fixed dimensions to your divs etc and keep it pretty fluid, that way they cant overlap or break your layout!